# SMT electret microhone PCB mounting

Tags: pcb-design, layout, microphone

I see a lot of SMT microphones in vendors' lineups. All of them orient normal to the PCB--either up or down. I'm working on a design where the microphone has to point parallel to the PCB.

On the prototype, I ran wires to the microphone from the PCB. In production, I would prefer an SMT part, and I prefer to point it the same way the the one in the picture.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be a shopping question, which isn't what this site is about.

Comment: Telephone builders most often mount their electrets inside a rubber-like shroud for acoustic isolation, and take the trouble to connect to a PCB with two flying leads.

Answer (score 1):

Can you 3D print a shroud (audio waveguide, whatever) that snaps onto the PCB and interfaces the outside world to the microphone?  If you're not Bose you'll probably lose a bit of fidelity, but I suspect not much.

Comment: The microphone is a secondary feature on this device. The budget for designing and manufacturing custom waveguides is low.